React native expo project not building android with react-native-google-mobile-ads module
So I have this react native expo project that I cloned from my own repository from github. Once I cloned the project and tried to build it with
npx eas-cli build --profile development --platform android
It does not work, and it gives me this error:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-google-mobile-ads:compileDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
   > Compilation error. See log for more details
* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
BUILD FAILED in 3m 57s
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.

Here is my app.json:
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "Timepal",
    "slug": "TimePal",
    "version": "1.2.1",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "android": {
      "permissions": [
        "android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM",
        "POST_NOTIFICATIONS"
      ],
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
      },
      "package": "com.mirceagodiac.timepal"
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    },
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
      }
    },
    "owner": "mariusdarius"
  },
  "react-native-google-mobile-ads": {
    "android_app_id": "ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "ios_app_id": "ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  }
}


And here is my package.json:
{
  "name": "timepal",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@preact/signals-react": "^1.3.6",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.23.1",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "8.0.1",
    "@react-native-masked-view/masked-view": "0.3.1",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.11",
    "@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs": "^6.2.19",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.8",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.14",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.20",
    "@uiball/loaders": "^1.3.0",
    "expo": "^51.0.32",
    "expo-constants": "~16.0.2",
    "expo-contacts": "~13.0.5",
    "expo-dev-client": "~4.0.26",
    "expo-device": "~6.0.2",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~13.0.2",
    "expo-notifications": "^0.28.16",
    "expo-splash-screen": "^0.27.5",
    "expo-sqlite": "~14.0.6",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.12.1",
    "fix": "^0.0.3",
    "location-picker": "^1.1.1",
    "luxon": "^3.4.4",
    "moment": "^2.30.1",
    "moment-precise-range-plugin": "^1.3.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.74.5",
    "react-native-actions-sheet": "^0.9.0-alpha.24",
    "react-native-calendars": "^1.1301.0",
    "react-native-dropdown-select-list": "^2.0.5",
    "react-native-event-listeners": "^1.0.7",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.16.1",
    "react-native-google-mobile-ads": "^12.11.0",
    "react-native-gradients": "^2.0.1",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.8.3",
    "react-native-loading-spinner-overlay": "^3.0.1",
    "react-native-multiple-select": "^0.5.12",
    "react-native-paper": "^5.11.4",
    "react-native-place-picker": "^2.7.0",
    "react-native-push-notification": "^8.1.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.10.1",
    "react-native-responsive-fontsize": "^0.5.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.10.5",
    "react-native-screens": "3.31.1",
    "react-native-select-contact": "^1.6.3",
    "react-native-select-dropdown": "^3.4.0",
    "react-native-svg": "15.2.0",
    "react-native-timer-picker": "^1.5.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^10.0.3",
    "react-navigation": "^5.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.24.0",
    "@types/luxon": "^3.4.1",
    "@types/react": "~18.2.79",
    "typescript": "~5.3.3"
  },
  "private": true
}


I tried to look around on some other stackoverflow questions, they suggested to change the kotlin version to 1.8.22, I did, but it didn't work.
To change the kotlin version, I changed the build.gradle file from this:
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = findProperty('android.buildToolsVersion') ?: '34.0.0'
        minSdkVersion = Integer.parseInt(findProperty('android.minSdkVersion') ?: '23')
        compileSdkVersion = Integer.parseInt(findProperty('android.compileSdkVersion') ?: '34')
        targetSdkVersion = Integer.parseInt(findProperty('android.targetSdkVersion') ?: '34')
        kotlinVersion = findProperty('android.kotlinVersion') ?: '1.9.23'

        ndkVersion = "26.1.10909125"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle')
        classpath('com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin')
        classpath('org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin')
    }
}

apply plugin: "com.facebook.react.rootproject"

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url(new File(['node', '--print', "require.resolve('react-native/package.json')"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim(), '../android'))
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url(new File(['node', '--print', "require.resolve('jsc-android/package.json', { paths: [require.resolve('react-native/package.json')] })"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim(), '../dist'))
        }

        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
}


To this:
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = findProperty('android.buildToolsVersion') ?: '34.0.0'
        minSdkVersion = Integer.parseInt(findProperty('android.minSdkVersion') ?: '23')
        compileSdkVersion = Integer.parseInt(findProperty('android.compileSdkVersion') ?: '34')
        targetSdkVersion = Integer.parseInt(findProperty('android.targetSdkVersion') ?: '34')
        kotlinVersion = '1.8.22'

        ndkVersion = "26.1.10909125"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle')
        classpath('com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin')
        classpath('org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin')
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:${getExtOrDefault('kotlinVersion', '1.8.22')}"
    }
}

apply plugin: "com.facebook.react.rootproject"

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url(new File(['node', '--print', "require.resolve('react-native/package.json')"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim(), '../android'))
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url(new File(['node', '--print', "require.resolve('jsc-android/package.json', { paths: [require.resolve('react-native/package.json')] })"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim(), '../dist'))
        }

        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
}


If you need any other info, please tell me.
Thanks in advance
